# Counter/Storage Collector + Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to design a storage system where excess energy goes into it. There is a cap of a maximum storage size for the system. I am struggling to work out how to code this in matlab.

Currently im using a function similar to this

```
max_storage = no_tanks*tank_size

if cumsum(excess) > 0 
   storage = cumsum(excess)
elseif cumsum(excess) < 0
```

After that I am confused how to continue writing the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: To make this problem solvable without mind reading, you need to be more specific about what you want, and preferably include a *reproducible* example.

Comment: One red flag I see so far: you are using [CUMSUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html) on the variable `excess`, which suggests to me that `excess` is a vector, which would mean that the output from CUMSUM is also a vector, which means that the expression `cumsum(excess) > 0` in your if statement is also a vector. You should pay special attention to how vectors are treated when used in [if statements](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/if.html).

Answer (score 0):

Attempt at mind-reading, while awaiting an update to the question.

To limit the storage size to `max_storage`, you need to have some code like

```
storage = calc_storage(excess);      % or whatever
storage = min(storage, max_storage);
```

Don't forget to finish your statements with `;`, and if you need to use `cumsum(excess)` lots of times it is better to assign it to a variable rather than calculating it over and over again.